# Value behaviour within an object

Tags: scala

I'd like some clarification on the below code:

```
object A {
  val value: String = test
}

def test: String = {
  println("potato")
  "potato"
}

A.value // produces "potato" as stdout and assigns the value "potato" to `value`

A.value // further calls do NOT print "potato" to stdout
```

Here's my explanation for this behaviour.

Here the function `test()` is being *executed once* and the *value* of the function (which is "potato") is being assigned to `value`. Further calls to `value` simply invoke the stored value without recalling the function.

Can anyone confirm?

Also, is there any way to *force* the function to be re-called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little more to it. Consider the following.

```
object A {
  val value: String = test
  val num = 55
}

def test: String = {
  println("potato")
  "potato"
}

// first reference to A
A.num  // produces "potato" to stdout and assigns the value "potato" to A.value
```

If `A.value` is declared a `lazy val` then `test` won't be called until the first reference of `A.value`. If `A.value` were a `def` then `test` would be called on every reference to `A.value`.

Comment: I think you're saying that once the object is referenced, it will execute all the value assignment code (excluding lazy) but upon further calls to that object, the value code will not be re-executed b/c of immutability.

Comment: The first reference to an `object` executes all of its code, assignments, side effects, etc. Immutability isn't an issue: every `var` or `val` is assigned its value immediately. A `lazy val` is executed (assigned its value) on first reference. A `def` is executed on every reference. It's just like all the code outside of an `object` except that if the object is never referenced then the code is never executed/initialized.

Answer (score 2):

I confirm, that's what's happening.

You could do something like:

```
object A {
  def value: String = test
}

def test: String = {
  println("potato")
  "potato"
}
```

transforming the attribute into a method, thus call the method test at each call.

With Scala synctatic sugar, you could still have a `A.value` syntax.

Would that be satisfying?

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Actually the point of this exercise is more just asking about the internal workings of scala & not so much about getting a particular result.